# which of the following option is correct?

Tags: linear-algebra

let  $V$ and $W$ be finite  dimensional vectors spaces and

let $A$ be  a linear transformation from $V$ to $W$ .then

which of the  following statements  is True ?

$1)$if  $V= W$ and $Im A \subseteq Ker A$ ,then $A  = 0 $

$2)$if  $V= W$ and $Im A \subseteq Ker A$ ,then $A^2  = 0 $

according to me .. Boths statement  is false  .that is if $V= W$, then  $A$  will  invertible.  as  Im  confused...now.

how  to thinks  ??

Any hints/solution will be appreciated

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. is false. Consider $A=\begin{bmatrix}0&1\\0&0\end{bmatrix}$ which satisfies $\operatorname{Im}A = \operatorname{span}(e_1)$ and $\operatorname{Ker}A = \operatorname{span}(e_1)$.
2. is true since this implies that $$\operatorname{Im}A^2=\{A^2x : x\in\mathbb{R}^n\} = A\{Ax:x\in\mathbb{R}^n\} = A\operatorname{Im}A\subseteq A\operatorname{Ker}A = \{0\}$$ which implies that $A^2=0$.

Answer (score 1):

The second option is correct. Consider a linear transformation $A\colon V\to V$. By definition, 
$$\text{Ker}(A)=\{x\in V\,\colon A(x)=0\} \text{ and } \text{Im}(A)=A(V).$$

By hypothesis, we have that $A(V)\subseteq \{x\in V\,\colon A(x)=0\}.$

Applying $A$ to both sides, it follows that $A^2(V)\subseteq \{0\}$. This is sufficient to conclude that $A^2$ is identically zero.